# Is There A File Manager That Preserves the File Date When Copying Over Network?

Tags: networking, copy

I don't know why I just noticed this, it should have been obvious earlier.  When I copy files from my desktop or virtual machine to my server via file manager the original file date is not preserved.  The server shows the date and time of the copy.

I have googled some and I see that I could do it via command line but that would not be very convenient when I am copying groups of files.  Is there a file manager that maintains the original date when dragging and dropping to network folders?

Also, I am asking about date but I may be meaning timestamp - don't want to confuse things by vague terminology.

Thanks

Comment: Please specify how your desktop or VM accesses "network folders" on your server? Some options might be SMB/CIFS (samba), NFS, FTP, SFTP, SCP, WebDAV? (If you don't know, describe how you connect to the server.) What command did you find that is supposed to preserver the date? Did you check that it actually works in your environment? What date/timestamp do you mean? A file can have several time stamps: creation, modification, access, (on UNIX usually) inode change time, and maybe others. BTW: For large groups of files it might even be more convenient to use the command line than a file manager.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  Access is via SFTP .  The suggested command line command I found to preserve the date is the option -p with the copy command.  I did not yet try the command line method.  The date I am referring to is the 'modified' column in the file managers I use - Nemo and PCmanFM.  My assumption is that this date is just a part of the overall term timestamp; I understand that there are various time references in a Linux file.

Comment: No there is not as it is not a task for a filemanager to do that. It would be a task for the sFTP software you use as that is the one transferring the files and not the filemanager. One other method would be to tar the files and untar at the destiny. tar preserves timestamps.

Comment: Please don't use comments to provide requested information, [edit] your question instead. Instead of describing a command, copy&paste (or type) the exact command. What are the OSs of your desktop, virtual machine and server?

Answer (score 0):

In answer to my own question.

With the above response re:sFTP I used both Lucky Backup and/or FileZilla to achieve the task.  Files on the destination now match source.